# when I want to access fullname within the greet method, I get : TypeError: this.getFullName is not a function , how can I fix this ? thanks in advance

Tags: javascript, object, this, object-literal

```
let greetings = {
    fullName : "elham zeinodini",
    getFullName : () => {
        return this.fullName;
    },
    Greet : message => console.log(`${message} ${this.getFullName()} !!`)
}



console.log(greetings.fullName);

greetings.Greet("Hello");
```

Comment: first, you must understand the consequences of using an arrow function in there

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - The title should give a short summary of the actual problem. It is not meant to contain the whole "question". And please refrain from adding _"Thanks"_ in the question (or the title). If you get an answer that helps "thank" the author with an up-vote and accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let greetings = {
    fullName : "elham zeinodini",
    getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    },
    Greet(message) {
      console.log(`${message} ${this.getFullName()} !!`)
    }
}
console.log(greetings.fullName);
greetings.Greet("Hello");
```

Answer (score -1):

It means, quite literally, that the property `getFullName` on the context `this` is not a function. You're trying to invoke something that isn't a function.

Why is that? Because you can't use `this` like you are to refer to the surrounding object using an arrow function. Depending on your environment, it might refer to the window object (in the browser). And the window object doesn't have a function called `getFullName`. So that property evaluates to `undefined`. Which isn't a function, hence the error.

Use a "regular" function declaration instead. `getFullName: function() {...}`

Comment: And you haven't found a suitable duplicate for a close-vote?

Answer (score -2):

The issue is with your arrow functions, which don't allow you to capture the `this` context.

Rewrite as follows:

```js
let greetings = {
    fullName : "elham zeinodini",
    getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    },
    Greet(message){ 
        console.log(`${message} ${this.getFullName()} !!`)
    }
}



console.log(greetings.fullName);

greetings.Greet("Hello");
```